# Ajax ModalPopupExtender - Set scrollbars if the browser is too small

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [asp.net ModalPopupExtender : need to show scroll bar when overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419761/asp-net-modalpopupextender-need-to-show-scroll-bar-when-overflow)

All, 
     I have been searching on Google for 3-4 hours already but none of the answers really helps. 
     What I need to do is when the browser is too small and the modal popup is shown, the scroll bar on the browser will be set for the modal window instead of the background (main window).

Can anyone help?

Many thanks.