# scrollbar for modalpopup extender

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-ajax

I have following modal popup extender:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>


                                        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="lbl"
                                            PopupControlID="PnlUpdate" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"  >
                                        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

                                        <asp:Panel ID="PnlUpdate" runat="server" Width="500px" CssClass="popup" Height="500px" >
                                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpnlModal" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                                <ContentTemplate>
                                                    <table width="100%">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="right">
                                                                <table width="100%" align="center">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td class="Heading" align="center">
                                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblHeading" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                                <table align="center" width="70%">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="right" class="NormalText">
                                                                            <asp:DataList ID="dlMovies" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="1"
                                                                                Width="100%">
                                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                    <table align="center" width="70%">
                                                                                        <tr>
                                                                                            <td align="left">
                                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblMovieName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                                                            </td>
                                                                                        </tr>
                                                                                    </table>
                                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                                            </asp:DataList>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </ContentTemplate>
                                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                        </asp:Panel>
```

I want to have scollbar for it.

I refered [How can I make the modal popup scroll its contents with the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894311/how-can-i-make-the-modal-popup-scroll-its-contents-with-the-page) and made css like:

```
.modalBackground 
{
    overflow : auto ;
    background-color:Black ;
    filter:alpha(opacity=65);
    -moz-opacity:0.65;                     
    Opacity:0.65; 
}
```

but still scrollbar is not comming, (I have also mentioned Height="500px" for panel.

Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could enclose your panel contents in a div with a max-height and overflow: auto

```
<asp:Panel ID="PnlUpdate" runat="server" Width="500px" CssClass="popup" Height="500px" >
    <div id="Div1" runat="server" style="max-height: 500px; overflow: auto;">

        PANEL CONTENTS 

    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should give the CSS property to your 'popup' css class. Use the class like given below

`.popup {overflow : auto ; height: 500px; }`